# Can't match string using regular expression

Tags: regex, match

I'm a newbie to regex and I'm trying to come up with a regular expression that matches any string that begins with 2 or 1 number and has to end with a letter: For example: `03C`, `4B`, `34A`,

I came up with this regular expression: `^[0-9]{0,2}\w[A-Z]$` and it works most of the time but it also matches two letters i.e. `AA` or `CD`

How can I force at least one number at the beginning of the string? Strings should be no more than 3 characters long and use all uppercase letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close.

Change your regex pattern to:

```
^[0-9]{1,2}[A-Z]$
```

This will match strings that begin with either 1 or 2 numbers, and end with a single uppercase letter.

Answer (score 3):

Try this regular expression

```
^[0-9]{1,2}[A-Z]$
```

Comment: The final `{1}` isn't needed, since `[A-Z]` will only match once anyway.

Comment: Oops i just forgot that.. thnx